# Canonical & Dell APT repository for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, updates, 18.04, repository

I have recently updated from `16.04` to `18.04` and I wonder whether there will be new `apt` `repositories` for Ubuntu `18.04`? Because the old `apt` `repositories` for `xenial` were deactivated whilst the update as taking place. So my questions are:

1. When will there be new repos?
2. How will I know about them?
3. Who will tell me the new locations?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 18.04 sources.list will be generated automatically when upgrading: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

Comment: For the Dell repos, you'll need to check http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/bionic-dell/public/ which currently only has place-holders.